# UIProgressbar update method

Tags: iphone, ios, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

**Hello i'm trying to write a method that update a UIProgressbar !**

The problem is that when both of values arrive fine to the method (NSLog display values)
the division operation generate a bad_access when i run the application !!

I tried many messages from both value like intValue/inValue ...

Help me to solve this issue and how can I print values of NSNumber

```
-(void)UpdateProgressbar:(NSNumber *)currentOperationNumer TotalOperationNumber:(NSNumber*)n
{
     NSLog(@" operation : %i",currentOperationNumer);
     NSLog(@" total : %i",n);

     if (currentOperationNumer<=n) 
     {
        [downloadBar setProgress:(currentOperationNumer/n )];
    NSLog(@"progress !");
     }
     else
     {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try **[currentOperationNumber intValue]** in place of **currentOperationNumber** (or floatValue if setProgress expects a float).  So....

```
int myProgress = [currentOperationNumber intValue] / [n intValue];
[downloadBar setProgress:myProgress];
```

Actually, isn't it a float value it expects in there?

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber is an object wrapper for various primitive types, with what you are doing you are trying to divide a pointer by a pointer..

maybe try chaining the code to..

```
[downloadBar setProgress:([currentOperationNumer intValue] / [n intValue])];
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can print value by using following code**

```
-(void)UpdateProgressbar:(NSNumber *)currentOperationNumer TotalOperationNumber:(NSNumber*)n
{
     NSLog(@" operation : %@",currentOperationNumer);
     NSLog(@" total : %@",n);

     if (currentOperationNumer<=n) 
     {
        [downloadBar setProgress:(currentOperationNumer/n )];
    NSLog(@"progress !");
     }
     else
     {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

1. If you are not using XCode 4, then upgrade.
2. In XCode 4, press CMD-I to run Instruments.
3. Select the Zombies profile.  (Background:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are sending a message to a deallocated object.  Zombies turns on the zombie feature, so that objects with a retain count of 0 are not deallocated, but kept as a zombie.  The NSZombie class raises an exception whenever a message is sent to it - thus it can be trapped, and identified the point of origin.)
4. Run your app via Instruments.  When it crashes, Instruments will be brought to the foreground with a pop-up callout that indicates the memory that was freed but accessed.
5. You can click the little arrow in the lower right corner, this will give you that memory's alloc/retain/release history, and the code that performs the action.  Click on the source column, it will take you to that line in the code.

Comment: XCode 3 was just too difficult to debug this way.  4 is worth the small hit you will have in learning curve on the new interface.

Answer (score 0):

make it sure downloadBar.progress is a float and it's from 0.0 to 1.0 inclusive.

Please, try this:

float current = 0.0f;
float count = 100.0f;

while (stuff..) {
downloadBar.progress = current / count;
}

it should work without problems.